# swiper wont show all dinamic itens inside swiper-slide div

Tags: css, swiper.js

I'm using swiper to show diferent products categories, inside the div with class swiper-slide the products of a category are called in a dinamic way.But not all products are shown. Even with overflow or heigth 100% it does not show all products. could someone  help me with this?

this is the the part of the code that show the products:(the div "catalogobody" is where the products are introduced)

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-pagination" style="top:0px;bottom:0px;"></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">Placas</h2>
            <div id="catalogo" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
              <label for="rep"></label> <input id="rep" name="rep" type='hidden' class="form-control" value= "<?php echo $secCli;?>" readonly="readonly" autofocus>
              <div id="catalogoBody" ></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
              <h2 style="text-align:center;">Conjuntos</h2>
            <div id="catalogo" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
              <label for="rep"></label> <input id="rep" name="rep" type='hidden' class="form-control" value= "<?php echo $secCli;?>" readonly="readonly" autofocus>
              <div id="catalogoBody2" ></div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
              <h2 style="text-align:center;">Modulo 1</h2>
            <div id="catalogo" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
              <label for="rep"></label> <input id="rep" name="rep" type='hidden' class="form-control" value= "<?php echo $secCli;?>" readonly="readonly" autofocus>
              <div id="catalogoBody3" ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">Modulo 2</h2>
          <div id="catalogo" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
            <label for="rep"></label> <input id="rep" name="rep" type='hidden' class="form-control" value= "<?php echo $secCli;?>" readonly="readonly" autofocus>
            <div id="catalogoBody4" ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it was necessary to add the method update() after the products were created, so that the swiper could recognize all products.